# only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indice

Tags: python

Good afternoon/morning/evening

I am facing a problem since two days trying to implement a hidden Markov model using viterbi alogorithm but i am not successful.

i have as error : only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices.

**in line 41**,''the error is path, delta, phi = viterbi(pi, a, b, obs)''
**in line 35**, ''path[t] = phi[path[t+1], [t+1]]''

My code is:

'''

```
def viterbi(pi, a, b, obs):

nStates = np.shape(b)[0]
T = np.shape(obs)[0]

# init blank path
path = np.zeros(T)
# delta --> highest probability of any path that reaches state i
delta = np.zeros((nStates, T))
# phi --> argmax by time step for each state
phi = np.zeros((nStates, T))

# init delta and phi 
delta[:, 0] = pi * b[:, obs[0]]
phi[:, 0] = 0

print('\nStart Walk Forward\n')    
# the forward algorithm extension
for t in range(1, T):
    for s in range(nStates):
        delta[s, t] = np.max(delta[:, t-1] * a[:, s]) * b[s, obs[t]] 
        phi[s, t] = np.argmax(delta[:, t-1] * a[:, s])
        print('s={s} and t={t}: phi[{s}, {t}] = {phi}'.format(s=s, t=t, phi=phi[s, t]))

# find optimal path
print('-'*50)
print('Start Backtrace\n')
path[T-1] = np.argmax(delta[:, T-1])
#p('init path\n    t={} path[{}-1]={}\n'.format(T-1, T, path[T-1]))
for t in range(T-2, -1, -1):
    path[t] = phi[path[t+1], [t+1]]  #line35
    #p(' '*4 + 't={t}, path[{t}+1]={path}, [{t}+1]={i}'.format(t=t, path=path[t+1], i=[t+1]))
    print('path[{}] = {}'.format(t, path[t]))

return path, delta, phi

path, delta, phi = viterbi(pi, a, b, obs)  #line41
print('\nsingle best state path: \n', path)
print('delta:\n', delta)
print('phi:\n', ph) 
                           '''
```

Comment: Line 35 and 41 have been marked as comments on the code

Comment: what values can take pi,a,b,obs? Also, can you fix the indentation of your code?

Comment: @SergioR these are my values: **pi **= [0.27, 0.31, 0.42] ...
**a_df.loc[hidden_states[0]] = [0.65, 0.35]**
a_df.loc[hidden_states[1]] = [0.52, 0.48]

**a** = a_df.values   , b_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=observ_states, index=hidden_states)
b_df.loc[hidden_states[0]] = [0.23, 0.45, 0.32]
**b_df.loc[hidden_states[1]] = [0.35, 0.38, 0.27]
 **obs** = np.array([1,1,2,0,1,2,1,0,2,0,1,2,1,0,2,])

Comment: concerning the indentation , i have basically no pbs with it...It is when i was copying the code that i accidentally modified it here.

Comment: I still need more information to run your code so try this: check the type of the numbers stored in`path` before line 35 (but after line 34).

Comment: @SergioR what do you mean by before line 35 , but after line 34? I am confused .ON my code , if you look carefully i have indicated **line** 35** and **41**  through **comments**

Comment: Error in line 41 indicates there is an error in your function viterbi(). That error is line 35. What is the problem? Either t in path[t] is not an integer, or t+1 in path[t+1], or path[t+1] in phi[path[t+1] are not valid variables for indices to access np.array. That's why just before line 35 you need to check what type are those variables. Or maybe it's because you put brackets in the last [t+1] in line 35.